# How to send an attachment using Python Discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want my bot to send a file (not necessarily an image, could be a text file) to the channel when called. Here's my code snippet:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def send(ctx):
    area=ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_file(area, r"c:\location\of\the_file_to\send.png",content="Message test")
```

However, it gives me an error:
`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_file'`
I tried replacing `send_file` with `send` as another answer had suggested, but that didn't work either. What should be the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the [`File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.File) class:

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx):
    file = discord.File("myfilepath")
    await ctx.send(file=file, content="Message to be sent")
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer worked perfectly for my command. But when I tried making an on_message event of a similar type, it threw up an 'unhandled message' error. Could you help with this?

My code snippet for the event:

@bot.event
```async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.content[0]=="@":
        file=discord.file("filepath")
        await message.channel.send(file=file, content="Message to be sent")```

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure how to format code in comments :(, hope you can read it.

Comment: `File` is a class, make sure to capitalize it. Your error is in this line: `file=discord.file("filepath")`, change it to: `file=discord.File("filepath")`

Comment: Does this work with paths over the internet? For example, something like: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1110705866816114713/1164760632676073562/message.txt?ex=654462df&is=6531eddf&hm=b199cdbb2dce74251f466881e1947893e0ee74ebfa9d7b95ee413dc3202466ac&